# Convert matching arrays to one single array

Tags: php, arrays

i need your help, i have an array which look like this

```
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 2
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 2
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 2
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 12
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 12
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 12
)
```

and i need to convert it so it can look some thing like this so that array with the same key and value should not repeat. e.g

```
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 2
)
Array
(
    [vaccine_id] => 12
)
```

my code looks like this. i am using codeigniter framework.

```
$data['vaccManagment'] = $this -> Common_model -> get_info('manage_epi_vacc', '', '','*', array('uncode' => $this -> uri -> segment(3), 'fmonth' => $this -> uri -> segment(4)));
        $vaccManagmentDetail = $this -> Common_model -> fetchall('manage_epi_vacc_items_record', '','vaccine_id', array('uncode' => $this -> uri -> segment(3), 'fmonth' => $this -> uri -> segment(4),'manage_vacc_id'=>$data['vaccManagment']->recid));
        $newDetail = array();
        foreach($vaccManagmentDetail as $detail){
            print_r($detail);
        }exit;
```

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you show the code producing those arrays, and printing it?

Comment: yes sure i am doing it some thing like this. i am using codeigniter structure
$data['vaccManagment'] = $this -> Common_model -> get_info('manage_epi_vacc', '', '','*', array('uncode' => $this -> uri -> segment(3), 'fmonth' => $this -> uri -> segment(4)));
  $vaccManagmentDetail = $this -> Common_model -> fetchall('manage_epi_vacc_items_record', '','vaccine_id', array('uncode' => $this -> uri -> segment(3), 'fmonth' => $this -> uri -> segment(4),'manage_vacc_id'=>$data['vaccManagment']->recid));
  $newDetail = array();
  foreach($vaccManagmentDetail as $detail){
   print_r($detail);
  }exit;

Comment: Please edit the question so we can read it :)

Comment: [This should solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `array_unique`

Refer:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Thanks for you interest. but, array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array. In may case arrays are different but there key and values are matching.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine them and have unique on base of values then your code should update like this:

```
$data['vaccManagment'] = $this -> Common_model -> get_info('manage_epi_vacc', '', '','*', array('uncode' => $this -> uri -> segment(3), 'fmonth' => $this -> uri -> segment(4)));
$vaccManagmentDetail = $this -> Common_model -> fetchall('manage_epi_vacc_items_record', '','vaccine_id', array('uncode' => $this -> uri -> segment(3), 'fmonth' => $this -> uri -> segment(4),'manage_vacc_id'=>$data['vaccManagment']->recid));
$arr= array_column($vaccManagmentDetail, "vaccine_id");
print_r(array_unique($arr));      
exit;
```

note, Removed your foreach code and added two line code that is:

```
$arr= array_column($vaccManagmentDetail, "vaccine_id");
print_r(array_unique($arr));exit;
```

Output should look like this:

```
array([0]=>1,[3]=>2,[6]=>12)
```